# How to search for list of keyword with Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using ElasticsearchRepository and I want to search some keywords. What I want to query is like;

```
//Get all results which contains at least one of these keywords
public List<Student> searchInBody(List<String> keywords);
```

I have already created a query for single keyword and It works but I don't know how to create a query for multiple keywords. Is there any way to do this?

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends 
ElasticsearchRepository<Student, String> {

    public List<Student> findByNameOrderByCreateDate(String name);

    @Query("{\"query\" : {\"match\" : {\"_all\" : \"?0\"}}}")
    List<ParsedContent> searchInBody(String keyword);

}
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: @Ahmet I have created a custom repo query like https://www.mkyong.com/spring-data/spring-data-add-custom-method-to-repository/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can pass an array of `String` objects in `ElasticsearchRepository`. 
Elasticsearch provides [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) for that.

Also You have to use `JSONArray` instead of `List<String>` i.e. you have to convert your `List<String>` to `JsonArray`. (Reason: check syntax of elastic query provided below)

Here is how you can use it in your code:

```
@Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": {\"terms\": {\"your_field_name\":?0}}}}")
List<ParsedContent> searchInBody(JSONArray keyword);
```

Result will contain objects with atleast one keyword provided in your keyword array.

Following is rest request representation of above java code that you can use in your kibana console or in terminal:

```
GET your_index_name/_search
{
 "query" : {
            "bool": {
                     "must": {
                              "terms": {
                                       "your_field_name":["keyword_1", "keyword_2"]
                                       }
                             }
                    }
           }
}
```

Note: For more options, You can check [terms-set-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html#query-dsl-terms-set-query)

Comment: This works for me but I had to use com.google.gson.JsonArray whereas I believe you used net.minidev.json.JSONArray